# Groups not visible from Workgroup Manager

Tags: macos, mac

On my mac osx server (10.6), Workgroup Manager shows no groups (/Local/Default). In inspector I can see all standard groups (like Staff etc.), and they looks OK - have GUIDs, RecordNames, AppleMetaNodeLocation = /Local/Default etc.

Users are visible but I cannot find why Groups are not displayed - either connecting remotely or running WM localy. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workgroup Manager normally hides "system" users and groups, but you can change this by selecting "Show System Records" from the View menu.